# How to fire concurrent lambda execution given a set of values parameter?

Tags: node.js, input, lambda, serverless

Hello I'm successfully using serverless framework to invoke a scheduled lambda function.

Let's say this lambda should run N times for each value in a set as parameter input

```
e.g. input ['a','b','c'....]
```

this is the portion of func def on my serverless.yml:

```
cacheRefresh:
 handler: handler.cacheBrowseAll
 timeout: 900
 events:
  - schedule: rate(1 minute)
```

instead of having on my handler:

```
cacheBrowseAll(){
    ['a','b','c'....].foreach(p => do something)
}
```

how can I possibly declare a loop of simoultneous lambda invokes inside the yml file?

I know I can define N func on yml using as input :

```
   input:
        key1: value1
```

But I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it can't be done with yaml. But you can can easily create a Lambda triggered by cron that will invoke your N functions.